# Strange behavior of equilibrium constant when most of the components are solids / pure liquids

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, kinetics

Consider the reaction $\alpha A(g) + \beta B(s) +\gamma C(s) +\cdots \rightleftharpoons \delta D(s)+\epsilon E(s)+\cdots $, so the chemical equilibrium constant should be $\dfrac{1}{[A]^\alpha}$, which is only dependent on the concentration on $A$. However, if I throw in a huge amount of $A(g)$ into the system, then it's possible that at least one of the reactants will be depleted before even reaching the equilibrium. So I have a few questions:

- Is my deduction correct and does this situation exist in reality?
- And furthermore, in more extreme scenarios when all the reactants and products are solid or pure liquid, then is the reaction still considered *reversible* since adding anything into the system won't change the reaction quotient and any state can be considered as an equilibrium?

Comment: These aren't extreme scenarios. It's just that all this plugging concentration thing you think about is limited. There's a tonne of reactions that *don't* depend on concentration at all. Well, at least not in the way this stuff^ works.

Comment: As a simple example, consider melting a solid. At the melting point, you can add or remove any amount of liquid or solid (assuming that what you add is already at the correct temp) and the system will remain in equilibrium as long as there is non-zero solid and liquid. This is of course also very much a reversible reaction.

Comment: An example would be $\ce{B(s) + (1/2)N2(g) = BN(s)}$ which has a equilibrium constant $K_e = p_{N2}^{-1/2}$ (=$173.5$ at $1900$ K) taking the activities of the solids to be $1$. There is nothing unusual about this, the equilibrium is always established even if one species is there in minute amounts as a result. Adding one species results in the others changing also.